# Barometric Sensor Library: Compilation Issues

Tags: c++, arduino, sensors, intel-galileo

I just got an `Intel Galileo` development board, and I am trying to get the [`Adafruit_BMP085_Unified` driver](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_BMP085_Unified) working. I noticed that the `Adafruit_Sensor` source had a reference to the *pgmspace.h* header file, and there's no support for the avr library on the Galileo yet, but I found a temporary header file to replace that.

Now I am having further compilation errors, and I can't pinpoint the issue. Here's the error I am getting.

```
Adafruit_BMP085_Unified/Adafruit_BMP085_U.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI23Adafruit_BMP085_Unified[_ZTI23Adafruit_BMP085_Unified]+0x8): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Adafruit_Sensor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm running this Arduino example under the Galileo development IDE `Arduino-1.5.3`. I am new to C++, so this is one big learning experience. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You also need https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Sensor.
Adafruit_Sensor is the base code, and the library you are using is like plugin, it can't work alone.